# My .loc with multiple conditions keeps running...help me land the plane

Tags: pandas

When I try to run the code below, it just keeps running. Is it something obvious?

```
df.loc[(df['Target_Group'] == 'x') & (df['Period'].dt.year == df['Year_Performed'].dt.year), ['Target_P']] = df.loc[(df['Target_Group'] == 'x') & (df['Period'].dt.year == df['Year_Performed'].dt.year), ['y']]
```

Comment: Not clear, if you could  provide clear picture of your complete requirement, that will be great. Kindly post samples of input and expected output too in your post and let us know.

Answer (score 1):

`pandas` is `index` sensitive , so you do not need repeat the condition for assignment

```
cond=(df['Target_Group'] == 'x') & (df['Period'].dt.year == df['Year_Performed'].dt.year)
df.loc[cond, 'Target_P'] = df.y
```

More info, example

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'cond':[1,2],'v1':[-110,-11],'v2':[9999,999999]})
df.loc[df.cond==1,'v1']=df.v2
df
Out[200]: 
   cond    v1      v2
0     1  9999    9999
1     2   -11  999999
```

---

If index contain duplicate

```
df.loc[cond, 'Target_P'] = df.loc[cond,'y'].values
```

Comment: Why not? Can you explain more?

Comment: @jezrael check the example :-)

Comment: Yes, it working, I know, but I think it is good idea have mask in both sides.

Comment: @jezrael i usually doing this in R , since pandas have this small benefit ...Just became lazy : -)

Comment: hmmm, not 100% sure, but if not default index there should be problem, but maybe problem in some old version of pandas (I once have problem if use your solution, but this was som kind of non standard index, maybe duplicated or similar).

Comment: @jezrael then should using values after filter

Answer (score 1):

I think you need assign condition to variable and the reuse:

```
m = (df['Target_Group'] == 'x') & (df['Period'].dt.year == df['Year_Performed'].dt.year)
df.loc[m, 'Target_P'] = df.loc[m, 'y']
```

For improve performance is possible use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['Target_P'] = np.where(m, df['y'], df['Target_P'])
```